# How would you associate location data with a post?

Tags: custom-post-types, api

I'm just wondering how you would associate several addresses to a post. My first guess is to create a custom post type with custom fields, then make an API call to Google Maps for the long and lat, store store that in the database, and query it. Seems like a sloppy solution though. How would you do it?

Comment: That's what I do. It's fast. Sloppy would be making the API call to get lat/long on every post view. I've seen that done a few times - yikes.

Comment: @shanebp Good to know, it's interesting that there isn't a whole lot of location related things on Wordpress around the web. Yikes! That must be brutal on page load time. Hopefully you've only seen it on a contact page.

Comment: Maybe it is just me  but I don't get what is the "it" in "How would you do it?". I would do it differently in every project based on the specific requirements of the project.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you think storing data in database would be sloppy, that's after all what they are for. There is nothing wrong with doing that.

Since the lat/long is unlikely to change unless there is a cataclysmic earth moving event, the data can be considered pretty static, you're not going to re-query Google once you get the initial lat/long.

An alternative way is to store it in a .json file or better store it an array (json) and cache it (this is what I do), since your most likely using Javascript to read the values into a map, especially if your reading tons of values.